# Having trouble getting my else statement to print in a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Still very new to Python, so I apologize if anything in here is off. This is for a program where you enter a number, and get back a value. You have to enter a number, so I'm trying to make it say "different values needed" when the user enters a string. However, I have an int() around the input, which means I get the following error when I input a string:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

My code is as follows:

```
while True:
 OVR = int(input('OVR?'))
 if OVR == 0:
   break
 elif OVR < 50:
   print('0.75M')
 elif OVR >= 50 and OVR < 60:
   print('8M')
 elif OVR >= 60 and OVR <= 70:
   print('15M')
 elif OVR > 70 and OVR <= 82:
   print('30M')
 elif OVR > 82:
   print("He's the GOAT, what do you think he wants?")
 else:
   print('different values needed')
```

I know it's probably a bad idea to have all those elifs, so I will eventually consolidate that into one formula. As said earlier, my main goal is that I want to make this so that it prints "different values needed" when the user enters a string. I've considered a try/except statement, but if I'm understanding them correctly, they are not really for calculating and printing things, and also couldn't take these elifs.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993238/python-invalid-literal-for-int-base-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `int` conversion in a `try`/`except` block.

```
while True:
    try:
        OVR = int(input('OVR?'))
    except ValueError:
        print('different values needed')
        continue
    # OVR an integer value, handle it as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! This seems like a pretty simple solution and I will try to remember this for the future. Looks like I just misunderstood how the try/except was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/except statement to print a message.

```
try:
    OVR = int(input("OVR?"))
except ValueError:
    print("different values needed")
```

Comment: Thanks! I initially misunderstood how to use the try/except statements.

Comment: Yes, no problem. However, I noticed that when using this in my program, in the later lines there are arithmetic calculations which will still return an error if a string is entered. So what Igor Raush has suggested is good because it'll keep looping until a valid integer is entered (I believe). I'm also quite new to python myself!

Comment: Have a look at this, I asked a very similar question myself and the individual who responded explained everything in his answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224243/printing-message-rather-than-valuerror-in-an-integer-user-input  Sorry for the multiple comments...I'm on tablet at the moment and it's giving me grief